# 'make run clean' shell script that properly handles interupts

Tags: makefile, csh

My first jab at writing a shell script that would run my makefile, run the executable, and then remove the executable looked like:

```
make
if [ -e a.out ]; then
    ./a.out
    rm a.out
fi
```

after realizing that the script didn't clean up `a.out` when I pressed `^C`, I tried modifying it like so:

```
onintr foo
make
if [ -e a.out ]; then
    ./a.out
    rm a.out
fi
foo:
    rm a.out
```

but it did not solve my problem. If any of you know how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do that would be very helpful.

Comment: btw I don't write shell scripts often so if I'm doing something really badly don't be mean :p

Comment: How exactly is this question related to the interrupt and interrupt-handling tags?

Comment: when you press `ctrl-c` doesn't it issue an interrupt?

Comment: You really want csh and makefile tags for this one.  You'll get less attention from confused folks and more attention from makefile and csh experts.

Comment: I suspect that the timing of your ctrl-c plays a role here.  While make is running, it gets the keyboard, not csh, and make is probably running >90% of the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Add an infinite loop at the top of your script, print out a line in your onintr routine and test that you hit it when you break the loop with Ctrl-C.  Remove the extra ouput and the infinite loop. Read your man pages on make, you probably don't have much control over what happens when it gets interrupted. That's why so many make files have a Clean target in them, so you can rerun make to clean-up all of its outputs.